# How do you make veggie chips tender?

Tags: chips, air-frying

I recently discovered how quick and easy it is to make thin slices of veggies on the mandolin if you use safety gloves.

Now I'm considering using my newfound power to make veggie chips, except I've never in my life has a veggie chip that wasn't way too hard and way too crunchy.   They always cut up the roof of my mouth and feel like I'm eating a piece of tree bark.

I'm looking to find a way to cook mandolinned veggies in my convection oven that aren't going to destroy my palate, but all I can find in Google is "USE THIS RECIPE TO MAKE THE CRISPIEST VEGGIE CHIPS EVER!"

That's...the opposite of what I want?  How can I make chips that are more like Lays potato chip consistency, without veering into "too crunchy" territory?  Do I just need to slice them thin enough?  Use a higher oven temp, like making soft cookies? Do I have to fry them, or can I air-fry? Do some veggies come out more tender than others?

Comment: I'm confused; you say you don't want your veggie slices to be crispy, but then you say you want them to be like potato chips.  What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't know how to describe it succinctly.  Not difficult to chew, without being soft?  Crispy, but not so crispy it carves up my palette (and every experience I've had has erred on the "too crunchy" side).  Maybe "crunchy" is a better description of what I'm trying to avoid...  I tried to make some edits, is it more clear?

Comment: "Crispy" doesn't mean "hard", it means "brittle". A potato chip is crispy. A dinner plate is not. Have you tried those recipes?

Comment: Would the difference between regular and 'kettle cooked' potato chips be similar to your crispy distinctions?

Comment: @wumpusD'00m Yes!  'Kettle cooked' chips also have the "slice up the roof of my mouth" problem, but the only way I can think to describe the texture is "crispier than normal potato chips, to the point of being unpleasant."  Any time I've had others' home-cooked veggie chips or bought them in bulk it's the same deal.

Comment: I don't eat them very often but the crispiest veg chips I've had have been the thinnest - on a par with thick potato crisps.  A lot of veg chips are thicker and I reckon that's why they seem so hard.  I *think* you need to go really really thin, but then they'll burn easily